# How to get json file into panda dataframe python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

How can I get this json file in a python dataframe? https://data.cdc.gov/resource/8xkx-amqh.json

I tried to read the data using socrata and was working. However it has a limit and I need the whole data.

That's what I have:

```
client = Socrata("data.cdc.gov", app_token=None)

# First 5000 results, returned as JSON from API / converted to Python list of
# dictionaries by sodapy.
vcounty = client.get_all("8xkx-amqh", limit=5000)


# Convert to pandas DataFrame
vcounty_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(vcounty)
```

But I want the whole data and for what I understand Socrata has a limit which is less than what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API is limited for unauthorized users but you can download all data in csv format and convert them to dataframe. **There are 1.5+ millions rows.**

```
# pip install requests
# pip install pandas

import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

urlData = requests.get('https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/8xkx-amqh/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD').content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(urlData.decode('utf-8')))
df
```

Returns

[image: ![enter image description here]